# Passing array of struct to a function

Tags: c, function, struct

I'm trying to pass data of a struct between the main and another function (on a different file .c) with no success. I have a struct like this

```
struct player{
    char name[10];
    int budget;
};

typedef struct player Player; 

void PrintFunc(Player p); //function prototype

Player gamer[2] = {{"Alice", 100},
                   {"Bob", 100 }};
```

And I call it from the *main* func with something like

```
PrintFunc(gamer);
```

The *function* structure should be something like this

```
void PrintFunc(Player p){
//stuff
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are sending an array of player objects and trying to receive it in single player object

Comment: What happens when you compile and run? Wh adrt does `PrintFunc` look like?

Answer (score 2):

`gamer` is an array, `PrintFunc` expects a single object.

Option 1:

```
PrintFunc(gamer[0]);
PrintFunc(gamer[1]);
```

Option 2: change the function to accept a pointer to `Player` objects:

```
void PrintFunc(Player *p, size_t len){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        // do something with p[i]
}

int main(void)
{
    Player gamer[2] = {{"Alice", 100},
                   {"Bob", 100 }};

    PrintFunc(gamer, sizeof gamer / sizeof *gamer);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void PrintFunc(Player p[]){ 
    //stuff 
}
```

Receive array of player objects when sending array of player objects